# Account copying question from another source

Tags: discussion

My concern is around this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1004955/break-in-operation-file-is-corrupt-what-to-do

The user posting the question has no other interaction on Super User, at this time. The question is not particularly suspicious, except that it is an [exact copy from a question posted on another site](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/313665-winrar-problem) back in 2009. Exact down to the extra space inside the beginning of the quote.

That site answers the question, so it’s not clear why the user is posting it on superuser. It could be useful to do so, probably attributed, if also posting an answer. Alternatively, it could be useful to generate some up-votes in order to start spamming.

So… what’s going on? How should something like this be handled?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention I guess. how did you find that by the way?

Comment: Was actually searching for an answer, seeing if it was something I could help answer. Lucky Googling, I guess.

Comment: That's so funny. He did give it a title though, and tags and removed the trailing `>`

Comment: So wierd. I'm going to leave the flag open and keep an eye on this for a bit, since to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what's the game here. If another mod is more familiar with this, we'll take action. Flagging is entirely appropriate and this is sooooo the sort of edge case the mod team should be made aware of.

Comment: @Random deleted it.... Perhaps he can share his reasoning?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek spammers use that very same tactic.